# Caliburn.Micro: call method on $dataContext from DataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, datagrid, caliburn.micro

`DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` is a list of `SomeService` items. SomeService class has a method `StopServiceAsync`:

```
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Content="Stop" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action StopServiceAsync($dataContext)]" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I want to stop a service right from a datagrid. If I bind button like this, I need to have a `StopServiceAsync(SomeService)` method in my **ViewModel**:

```
public async Task StopServiceAsync(SomeService service)
        {
            await service.StopServiceAsync();

        }
```

But in real life there are many methods `SomeService` holds, and I don't want to create each method's copy in a **ViewModel**. Is there any way to bind Button's Click action directly to `$dataContext`? Something like `cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action $dataContext.StopServiceAsync]"`?*(It does not work)*

Comment: Because the button is in the Datatemplate it doesn't understand who or what in relation to datacontext, probably going to need something like this ```cm:Bind.Model=”{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}}”``` on your button